# Jacoco code coverage in Android Studio with flavors

Tags: android, gradle, code-coverage, jacoco, test-coverage

I've been trying to run Jacoco test coverage for quiet some time now. I've tried several possible solutions reported in these topics:

[Android test code coverage with JaCoCo Gradle plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18358297/android-test-code-coverage-with-jacoco-gradle-plugin)

[How do I get a jacoco coverage report using Android gradle plugin 0.10.0 or higher?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23795595/how-do-i-get-a-jacoco-coverage-report-using-android-gradle-plugin-0-10-0-or-high)

Im running the tests in a emulatated device using genymotion. 
Here is what i added to build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'jacoco'

android{       
    jacoco {
        version "0.7.1.201405082137"
    }        
    buildTypes{
        debug{
                    testCoverageEnabled = true
        }
    }
}

jacoco {
    toolVersion "0.7.1.201405082137"
}
```

To run it i use something like

```
./gradlew clean
./gradlew createFLAVOR_NAMEDebugCoverageReport
```

The relevant generated files/folder are:

```
/build/intermediates/coverage-instrumented-classes
/build/intermediates/jacoco
/build/outputs/code-coverage/connected/flavors/MyFlavor/coverage.ec
```

However, there is nothing @ build/reports/jacoco/test/html/index.html or any html page/code coverage report @ /build/outputs.

I've also tried to create a dedicated task to build a coverage report:

```
def coverageSourceDirs = [
    'src/main/java',
]

task jacocoTestReport(type: JacocoReport, dependsOn: "connectedAndroidTestFLAVOR_NAMEDebug") {
    group = "Reporting"
    description = "Generate Jacoco coverage reports after running tests."
    reports {
        xml.enabled = true
        html.enabled = true
    }
    classDirectories = fileTree(
        dir: './build/intermediates/classes/debug',
        excludes: ['**/R*.class',
                   '**/*$InjectAdapter.class',
                   '**/*$ModuleAdapter.class',
                   '**/*$ViewInjector*.class'
        ])
    sourceDirectories = files(coverageSourceDirs)
    executionData = files("$buildDir/jacoco/connectedAndroidTestMyFlavorDebug.exec")
    // Bit hacky but fixes https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=69174.
    // We iterate through the compiled .class tree and rename $$ to $.
    doFirst {
       new File("$buildDir/intermediates/classes/").eachFileRecurse { file ->
            if (file.name.contains('$$')) {
                file.renameTo(file.path.replace('$$', '$'))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then **./gradlew clean** and **./gradlew jacocoTestReport**. The output is the same as above, so, no html page with coverage report or any other coverage file.

I'm currently using Android Studio v1.0.2 with the latest gradle version.
Im fairly new to gradle, so it is possible im missing something basic here.

Thanks

Comment: https://github.com/bumptech/glide/blob/master/library/build.gradle  sampl using your tool.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get code coverage using Android Studio?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18683022/how-to-get-code-coverage-using-android-studio)

Answer (score 10):

After spending the whole day chasing this issue i found out what's the problem. Contrary to the examples i've seen the file generated by the testDebug build is not the .exec file @**$buildDir/jacoco/testDebug.exec**.

With my gradle and studio version the file generated is a .ec @**build/outputs/code-coverage/connected/flavors/myFlavor/coverage.ec**

I didn't found any relevant information related to this. It may be a recent change, however, by creating a custom JacocoReport task and changing the executionData variable accordingly i've solved the problem.
Here is my implementation:

```
task jacocoTestReport(type: JacocoReport) {

  def coverageSourceDirs = [
        'src/main/java'
  ]

  group = "Reporting"
  description = "Generates Jacoco coverage reports"
  reports {
      xml{
          enabled = true
          destination "${buildDir}/reports/jacoco/jacoco.xml"
      }
      csv.enabled false
      html{
          enabled true
          destination "${buildDir}/jacocoHtml"
      }
  }

  classDirectories = fileTree(
          dir: 'build/intermediates/classes',
          excludes: ['**/R.class',
                     '**/R$*.class',
                     '**/BuildConfig.*',
                     '**/Manifest*.*',
                     '**/*Activity*.*',
                     '**/*Fragment*.*'
          ]
  )

  sourceDirectories = files(coverageSourceDirs)
  additionalSourceDirs = files(coverageSourceDirs)
  executionData = files('build/outputs/code-coverage/connected/flavors/smartcompanion/coverage.ec')
}
```

Comment: With all these hints I still have got a code coverage of 0% in the test reports although I run through testing an activity. But my reports are located in ``${buildDir}/reports/coverage/debug`` and not in ``${buildDir}/reports/jacoco/jacoco.xml`` or ``${buildDir}/jacocoHtml``. I already spent a lot of time for integrating Jacoco code coverage in my Instrumentation Tests and I used a lot of descriptions in posts. But still it doesn't run correctly. What's strange is that my ``coverage.ec`` file is empty.

Comment: Should this snippet exclude all Fragments and Activities? There could be code that needs testing in there.

Comment: @unlimited101 which device do you use? if using samsung it might be a problem. try using HTC, Motorola or else one